# convert arraylist into IList in vb.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, arraylist

I am getting an arraylist in view from controller. In view when i try to display that array error occur "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.ArrayList' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1". my code is as below

```
Dim c As IList(Of myclass) = CType(Model, IList(Of myclass)) (arraylist from controller)
```

In Model there is an arraylist. I don't know how to cast this arraylist into IList. Please help. Thanks

```
Dim iplist = (From d In db.mytable Select d).ToList
Dim c2 As ArrayList

For i As integer = 0 to iplist.Count - 1
    Dim ip = iplist(i).ip
    Dim c as countrylist
    c.country = country
    c.city = city
Next

Class cou1ntrylist
    Public country As String
    Public city As New ArrayList
End Class
```

Comment: you could use .ToList() on your array, remember to Import System.Linq. Also is there any reason why you want to use an Interface as a list? why can't you use List(Of Type)?

Comment: getting data from table and do some some on data that is achieved in arraylist. now sending arraylist to view. same problem with List(Of Type). is there any other way to display this data in view. Thanks

Comment: Post more code so we can see and understand what you are doing.

Comment: dim f = (from d in db.table select d).Tolist.   dim c2 as arraylist  for i as integer =0 to f.count-1 c2.country = f(i).country c2.city= f(i).city next country is only one but there is many cities in country list. i am getting these country and city names from ip address saved in table

Comment: Edit your original post above and post the whole method there. Posting it as a comment will not help much.

Comment: You create an ArrayList c2 and a countrylist c, you assign values to c but never add it to an array, nor do you use the ArrayList at all. This is either an oversight or you have not posted all the code.